# Using an imported Typescript function in Angular HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

I have a TypeScript utility class `myUtils.ts` as below:

```
export class MyUtils {
  static doSomething(input: string) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

I want to call this method in my component's HTML. In order to do that I imported this class in my component

```
import { MyUtils } from './utils'
```

and using in the component's HTML like so:

```
<ng-template #dynamicTableCell let-entry>  
  {{ MyUtils.doSomething(entry) }}
</ng-template>
```

The HTML is complaining with `Unresolved variable or type MyUtils`. Interestingly enough, I am able to do the same `MyUtils.doSomething(someEntry)` without any error in the component's `component.ts` file. It is just the HTML where it is complaining.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this problem in the HTML? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using an angular service instead of your utils class. In your html to your component you will be able to `{{newService.doSomething(entry)}}`

Comment: You can't, but it's not much trouble to add a proxy member to your component class `doSomething = MyUtils.doSomething;` and use that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use it, since template expressions are restricted to referencing members of the componence instance, you need to create the method in your component, or use Angular pipe in your case.

**component.ts**

```
import { MyUtils } from './utils';
...

doSomething(entry) {
  MyUtils.doSomething(entry);
}



// or

doSomething = MyUtils.doSomething;
```

You can have a look at [Template expressions](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation#template-expressions) doc.

Comment: Thanks, @coturiv! That really helped.

Answer (score 2):

import { MyUtils } from './utils';
...

**MyUtils= MyUtils;**

looks wierd but it's work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).